# How would I permanently apply CSS Transition/effect on a pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

not sure if I'm using the complete wrong method for this but I'm wondering how I would permanently apply an effect when hovered, if the item is clicked on, but for a pseudo element.

I've setup a tab style menu where a new page will open based on the currently selected tab and I have also setup the transition/effect I want it to apply when hovered, however, I want it to remain on that hovered effect when the user clicks on it. It will also need to remove that effect and apply to a different tab if the user decides to click on a different one.

While I understand basic adding of a class in jquery, I don't really understand how to do it with a pseudo element.

Here's some of my code ripped out of my project to simplify the snippet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#navigator div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#navigator {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(5px); */
}

.test-title{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  transition: color 0.18s;
}

.test-title:hover {
  color: white;
}

.test-title::after{
  display: block;
  transition: transform ease 0.25s;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.test-title:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigator">
      <div id="tes1" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">test1</h1></div>
      <div id="test2" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">testing2</h1></div>
      <div id="test3" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">testimus3</h1></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can't access pseudo elements using ```JavaScript``` or ```jQuery```. See this example, he did it perfectly [Aaron iker](https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/pezemX)

Answer (score 3):

You need add some Javascript and CSS. I made a snippet for you

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(element2 => element2.classList.remove('active'))
    element.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#navigator div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#navigator {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(5px); */
}

.test-title{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  transition: color 0.18s;
}

.test-title:hover,
.test.active {
  color: white;
}

.test-title::after{
  display: block;
  transition: transform ease 0.25s;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.test-title:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.test.active .test-title::after {
   transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.test.active > h1 {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigator">
      <div id="tes1" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">test1</h1></div>
      <div id="test2" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">testing2</h1></div>
      <div id="test3" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">testimus3</h1></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a hidden radio button to each item and apply style to it's siblings if it's checked:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#navigator label { /* changed */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#navigator {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(5px); */
}

.test-title{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  transition: color 0.18s;
}

.test-title:hover {
  color: white;
}

.test-title::after{
  display: block;
  transition: transform ease 0.25s;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.test > input:checked ~ .test-title::after, /* added */
.test-title:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

/* added */
.test > input
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigator">
      <label id="tes1" class="test"><input type="radio" name="test"><h1 class="test-title">test1</h1></label>
      <label id="test2" class="test"><input type="radio" name="test"><h1 class="test-title">testing2</h1></label>
      <label id="test3" class="test"><input type="radio" name="test"><h1 class="test-title">testimus3</h1></label>
 </div>
```

With this approach it will be a little difficult implement showing an appropriate page for a selected tab.
For that it better move the radio buttons to outside of tabs:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#navigator label { /* changed */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#navigator {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(5px); */
}

.test-title{
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  transition: color 0.18s;
}

.test-title:hover {
  color: white;
}

.test-title::after{
  display: block;
  transition: transform ease 0.25s;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 15% 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.container > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ #navigator :nth-child(1) .test-title::after, /* added */
.container > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ #navigator :nth-child(2) .test-title::after, /* added */
.container > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ #navigator :nth-child(3) .test-title::after, /* added */

.test-title:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

/* added */
.container > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ #navigator :nth-child(1) .test-title::after,
.container > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ #navigator :nth-child(2) .test-title::after,
.container > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ #navigator :nth-child(3) .test-title::after
{
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.container > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ #content :nth-child(1),
.container > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ #content :nth-child(2),
.container > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ #content :nth-child(3)
{
  display: initial;
}

#content > *,
.container > input
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="test1" type="radio" name="samename">
  <input id="test2" type="radio" name="samename" checked>
  <input id="test3" type="radio" name="samename">
  <div id="navigator">
      <label for="test1" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">test1</h1></label>
      <label for="test2" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">testing2</h1></label>
      <label for="test3" class="test"><h1 class="test-title">testimus3</h1></label>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div>Tab 1 content is</div>
    <div>Tab 2 content working</div>
    <div>Tab 3 content good</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is less robust approach and would require modifying both HTML and CSS when adding more tabs/pages.